# Difference between a phototroph and a photosynthetic organism?

Tags: terminology

A quick search on google about the topic and the page [on wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phototroph#Photoautotroph) did not help understanding the difference between these two related terms.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Practically**, 99% of the time there is no difference when using one term or another.

**More strictly:**

A phototroph ("[a thing nourished by light](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phototroph)") is according to your wiki page:

> It is a common misconception that **phototrophs are obligatorily photosynthetic**. Many, but not all, phototrophs often photosynthesize: they anabolically convert carbon dioxide into organic material to be utilized structurally, functionally, or as a source for later catabolic processes (e.g. in the form of starches, sugars and fats). All phototrophs either use electron transport chains or direct proton pumping to establish an electrochemical gradient which is utilized by ATP synthase, to provide the molecular energy currency for the cell. Phototrophs can be either autotrophs or heterotrophs.

and

> If their electron and hydrogen donors are inorganic compounds (e.g. $Na_2H_2SO_4$, as in some purple sulfur bacteria, or $H_2S$, as in some green sulfur bacteria) they can be also called lithotrophs, and so, some photoautotrophs are also called photolithoautotrophs.

So the difference resides in that some phototrophs do not carry out photosynthesis, which is a specific set of metabolic functions (those that do $CO_2$ --> organic compounds). An organism that carries out photosynthesis is then a *photosynthetic organism*.

In other words, photosynthetic organisms are a subset of phototrophs.